# Powershell: -or in a while loop

Tags: powershell, operators

What is wrong with my formatting. the code runs when only one condition is in there. When I add the -or with the second condition to check it appears to not check either.

```
    while(($TempLog.id -ne "18") -or ($TempLog.id -ne "32"))
    {
        $TempLog = Get-WinEvent -computername F9P8NW2-5300 -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-RemoteAssistance/Operational'-MaxEvents 1
    }
```

enter code here

Comment: The condition will always resolve to `$true`, so you have an infinite loop. E. g. when `$tempLog.id` is `"18"`, the condition resolves to `"18" -ne "18" -or "18" -ne "32"` -> `$false -or $true` -> `$true`.

Comment: You probably mean this: `while(-not ("18", "32" -eq $TempLog.id))`

Comment: Another way: `while($tempLog.id -notin '18', '32')`. Also I would add a `sleep` in the loop so you don't overload the computer with `Get-WinEvent` requests.

Comment: Thanks this advice resolved my issue.